# Finding resources in wpf with several levels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem when I have several levels or resources in wpf

for instance if i have this code

main.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="Main">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

sub.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="Sub" BasedOn="{StaticResource     Main}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

all.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:p19"
    >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Main.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Sub.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="All.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

in mainwindow i just have

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource Sub}"/>
</Grid>
```

This won't work.

However if I put resources directly into app.xaml (and not through all.xaml)  like this

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Main.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Sub.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

It does work. I think i remember that someone said somewhere (I can't remember where) that this is a bug in wpf and can be solved with some empty styles and with new .net framework.

I tried 2015 rc and 4.6 and it still doesn't work.

Does someone know how to fix it and where? And can they try out the code on their side to see if it works?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to put this dictionary in turn into a merged dictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="All.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Should work fine then.

**Edit**

However you get into trouble when you try to access a style from another dictionary. To get rid of this reference it in the sub.xaml too:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Main.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="Sub" BasedOn="{StaticResource Main}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This does work indeed. But i didn't state my question entirely correct I now see.

Comment: This does work indeed for this situation. But my situation is more complex. The sub shouldn't show exactly where main is defined(in my case main actually depends on the resolution). And usually you don't have to specify where the main style is right?

Comment: @6lix well if thats the case the main styles are not static are they?

Comment: depends what you mean by static. I just "inject" a different xaml resource based on the resolution. So you have a resource for all resolutions and then separate for each resolution. The problem is some kind of wpf bug I think